# How to check whether my shortcode callback is parsing for an excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a shortcode plugin, but I do not want to return any output if it is going to be used for an excerpt. How can I check whether it is called in an excerpt / non-full post context?

I found a [discussion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11048) that for semantic reasons, `is_excerpt()` is rejected, but there are no more clues that can be found in [other](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) [places](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) as well.

<strike>Maybe the shortcode plugin should be passed the `bool is_excerpt` as well...</strike>

**EDIT**: based on the [note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt#Comparison_with_more_quicktag)

> "The <!--more--> quicktag requires templates to use  the_content()
>   whereas using excerpts requires, and allows, template writers to
>   explicitly choose whether to display full posts (using the_content())
>   or excerpts (using the_excerpt())."

This means that the preferred solution must be able to account for both of these functions, i.e. `[myshortcode]` should return empty string if the full post is not being displayed.

Comment: By default, the_excerpt does not render shortcode. Are you using a theme that's calling `do_shortcode` in a custom excerpt callback?

Comment: I don't think so. I am using the default twentytwelve (I am using the latest WP version, though). Furthermore, it does not make sense the `the_excerpt()` does not `do_shortcode()`. wouldn't it cause all the tags to show?

Comment: It makes perfect sense that `the_excerpt` does not call `do_shortcode`. The excerpt is designed to only take in a set number of words and then render some "more" text once it reaches a certain threshold. All other images, special markup, and shortcode is ignored as it's content-oriented. `do_shortcode` is the function responsible for parsing the shortcode itself, so if it isn't called, no shortcode is rendered. In short: If you're using `the_excerpt`, no shortcode will be rendered.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got the terminologies wrong. I checked, the template is using `the_content('more link')` to render the posts for the home page. Somewhere in `the_content()`, my shortcode callback function is called. Your comment just gave me an idea to use `is_single()` and it works for this particular case for now, but is there a way to check if it is showing the full or "trimmed" post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. It's a little hacky, but there isn't much else I can think of to differentiate between paged content and full content:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mm_selective_shortcode');
function mm_selective_shortcode($content){
    global $pages;
    if(count($pages) > 1)) remove_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');
    return $content;
}
```

The issue is that you're not actually checking for an *excerpt*. You're checking for content (called by `the_content`) and whether or not that content has been broken up using the `<!--more-->` quicktag. Since Wordpress does not inherently differentiate between the two methods of display, it makes it difficult to ensure that shortcode is rendered differently between the two.

With that said, this will remove ALL shortcode on the given content if that content has been paginated. If you want to target only your own shortcode, try using this instead:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mm_selective_shortcode');
function mm_selective_shortcode($content){
    global $pages;
    if(count($pages) > 1)) remove_shortcode('myshortcode');
    return $content;
}
```

This code hasn't been tested, so I can't guarantee it will work straight out of the gate. But it should at least help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

What [Scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu) and [Hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) say on [that ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11048) is pretty much all about it. The former was a WP core developer and the latter is a SO power house...

What can be done is to filter the excerpt and remove the shortcode. That's easy if it's a simple self-enclosed shortcode `[example]` but  will need some [heavy Regex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L228) if not: `[example id="foo"]` or `[example]content[/example]`.

A simple filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function( $excerpt ) 
{
    return str_replace( '[myshortcode]', '', $excerpt );
});
```

Comment: Hakre get semantic reasons; while Scribu said " A themer should be able to find out wich actual template/query is using excerpts or not...." But the question is how?

Comment: I think they are commenting wrt to "`excerpt`" which has a specific definition in wordpress; and thus "`is_excerpt()`" was inappropriate. My issue on the other hand is more general with regards to partial posts display, so their comments do not really address my concern. Your answer here probably can help, although I am not sure whether `get_the_excerpt()` is also called within `the_content()`

Comment: No, it's called by `the_excerpt`. And I've seen nothing in WP core that could hint a way to detect if it's `the_content` or `the_excerpt` that's running.